# Checking for the intersection of a 4D line segment and a 4D convex polytope

Tags: c++, geometry, 4d

I have two 4D shapes: a polytope composed of two triangles with each side connected to the corresponding side on the other triangle (think triangular prism, but not necessarily straight) and a line segment.

I don't need to know where they intersect, just whether they intersect or not. How can I check for this?

Comment: Could you describe that polytope mathematically? It really sounds like a 3D object.

Comment: Don't you mean two tetrahedra with faces connected ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your convex polytope is delimited by a number of hyperplanes, of equation `ax+by+cz+dw+e = 0`. Considering a point inside the polytope, you can adjust the signs so that all inside points verify `ax+by+cz+dw+e ≥ 0` for all hyperplanes.

Now a line segment will have parametric equations like

```
x = (1-t)x'+tx''
y = (1-t)y'+ty''
z = (1-t)z'+tz''
w = (1-t)w'+tw''
```

and you can find the meeting points of the line `P'P''` with every hyperplane. You will discard those such that `t` is not in `[0,1]`, and discard those that are not in the positive side of the other hyperplanes. If you find some meeting point that fits, then the polytope and the segment do intersect.

Comment: How can I find a point that is inside the polytope in order to adjust the signs of the coefficients?